# How to print the entire shape without splitting it into two nested loops?

Tags: c++

I've tried to print the following shape:

```
*           
*   *       
*   *   *   
*   *   *   *
*   *   *   
*   *       
*
```

I splitted it into 2 nested loops. One for the first four lines (increment), another one for the last 3 lines (decrement) with the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*" << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    for (int i = 3; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << "*" << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
```

Is it possible to print this shape using only one nested loop?

Comment: yes it is possible. They way to get there is to take pen and paper and find a mapping from (0...number of rows) to number of stars in a row. Hint: taking the absolute value of some difference can come in handy

Comment: Consider what values the expression `i > 4 ? 8-i: i` will give if `i` runs from `1` to `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fun, based on [Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50172890/5470596) (but without the use of `std::string` and the missing whitespaces):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    for (int i = -3; i <= 3; ++i) {
        std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout), 4 - std::abs(i), "* ") = "\n";
    }
}
```

See [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).
See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13eb4cd8e8e96a02).

Answer (score 1):

As @user463035818 said in the comments, you can do it using absolute values. Here is how :

```
#include <cstdlib> // std::abs
for (int line = 1; line < 8; line++)
{
    int numberOfStars = 4 - std::abs(4 - line);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
        std::cout << "*" << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Pretty elegant and simple, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the whitespace between the asterisks then you can use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    for (int i = -3; i <= 3; ++i){
        std::cout << std::string(4 - std::abs(i), '*') << "\n";
    }
}
```

Only one loop: the inner loop is delegated to the `std::string` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 7) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 4) {
        if (i >= j && i + j < 7)
            std::cout << "* ";
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: without splitting it into two nested loops?

Comment: @rak007 there is only one nested loop

Comment: @Tyker This is working, but your second while does unnecessary loops. Could be a problem in case you wanted to apply this algorithm on bigger shapes.

Comment: @souki i know but i don't think the program is going to get big enough to see an impact knowing that it is drawing things on the output

Comment: @Tyker,  true I was just being a bit picky I guess